# Create link to value in taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, hyperlink, metadata

I have som users that wants a link directly to a value with children in the taxonomy navigation area.
Is this at all posible?
I have tested several ways, most of them work when i paste them in my browser, but not when I create an link with it.

I could set up a filter to filter out what the users want see, but the filter is already on the limit of what you can have on a filter, so I cant add any more to it.

Just to simplify (my english isnt perfect), users wants a link directly to the area marked in red, without going through the trouble of actualy pushing the button(yes, lazy users).

[image]